# Shell -Bash using Unix

Tags: shell, filenames

Hey i need to find file name which has different parts in its name and extension    which is is located in the given directory

```
Example-    part1_part2_part3.h
            partx_party_partz.h
            hi_exp.h
            bye.h
```

In this I need to find only `part1_part2_part3.h`, `partx_party_partz.h` files which is in correct format. How i have to design If condition?

Comment: What about `ls part*_part*_part*.h`?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%s\n' *_*_*.h
```

Would print the filenames that contain at least 2 underscores, don't start with `.` and end in `.h` one per line. When there's no such file however, it will print `*_*_*.h`.